# Is it possible to specify a default View for all Jersey resource methods?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jackson

Here's the situation.

I've a large codebase using Jersey 2.17, Jackson 2.6.3, and Spring 4.2.0.

I have quite a few models with a small subset of properties exposed with @JsonProperty. The rest are excluded by default.

There are many Jersey resource methods that **are not** using a `JsonView` annotation.

Enter me. I need to write some new internal API endpoints that expose a different subset of the internal/confidential model properties. I've annotated these "private" properties with `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonView(SuperSecretAndInternal.class)`.

The original, public, properties I've added a `@JsonView(PublicForEveryone.class)` annotation.

The problem is that there are many many resource method handlers that don't use specify a JsonView. The result is all properties (PublicForEveryone and SuperSecretAndIntenal alike) are being exposed.

---

Edit. Adding Example code.

```
// POJO - before
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = NONE, isGetterVisibility = NONE, fieldVisibility = NONE)
class Person {

    @JsonProperty
    String name;
    @JsonProperty
    String age;

    Date createdDate;
    String socialSecurityNumber;

    // getters/setters not shown
}
```

This was used in a Jersey method handler in a PublicAPIResource

```
@GET
@Path("/people")
public Person getUser(@PathParam("name") String name)
{
// get user by name, return user
}
```

and result in the json:

```
{ name: "Jane", age: 20 }
```

Now, I come along and want to expose the sensitive fields of the POJO in an alternate and private/internal API. So I modify the POJO like so:

```
// POJO - after
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = NONE, isGetterVisibility = NONE, fieldVisibility = NONE)
class Person {

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(PublicForEveryone.class)
    String name;

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(PublicForEveryone.class)
    String age;

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(SuperSecretAndInternal.class)
    Date createdDate;

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonView(SuperSecretAndInternal.class)
    String socialSecurityNumber;

    // getters/setters not shown
}
```

while creating the Views:

```
public class Views
{

    public static class PublicForEveryone
    {}
    public static class SuperSecretAndInternal extends PublicForEveryone
    {}
}
```

and I create *a new* Jersey resource handler in PrivateAPIResource

```
@GET
@Path("/internal/secret/people")
@JsonView( SuperSecretAndInternal.class )
public Person getUser(@PathParam("name") String name)
{
// get user by name, return user
}
```

which returns  the json:

```
{ name: "Jane", age: 20, createdDate: xxx, socialSecuritynumber: 123  }
```

But the **original** PublicAPIResource now returns the entire Person POJO because it does not have a @JsonView annotation. In this simple example I could simply add the annotation and be done, but in my real codebase, there are many resources, not to mention instances where the People POJO is a nested field in other models.

---

**Question:** Is there a way to specify a *default* JsonView per POJO/model? The intent is such that if a jersey resource method handler, does NOT specify a `@JsonView`, then the default one will be used, instead of just exposing every `@JsonProperty` annotated property.

If not, does anyone know another way I can achieve this, without modifying all my resource method handlers (because I can't)?

Could I provide a default serializer for the POJO that serializers it with the "default" view, but somehow allows explicit views to pass through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can is configure the default inclusion/exclusion, but I think this will not solve your problem. Have you check JsonFilter http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter, it has feature to defined default filter that can be applied to all pojos/models.

Example pojo:

```
class Person{
    String name;
    String age;
    Date createdDate;
}
class User{
    String username;
    String password;
    Date createdDate;
}
```

CustomAnnotationInspector:

```
public class CustomIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector
{
  @Override
  public Object findFilterId(AnnotatedClass ac) {
    // Let's default to current behavior if annotation is found:
    Object id = super.findFilterId(ac);
    // but use simple class name if not
    if (id == null) {
       id = "DEFAULT_FILTER";
    }
    return id;
}
```

Plug it to your ObejctMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// create filter with id "DEFAULT_FILTER" and configure it to exclude 'createdDate' property.
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("DEFAULT_FILTER",
SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("createdDate"));

JacksonAnnotationIntrospector jai = new CustomIntrospector ();

// plug the custom annotation that will use "DEFAULT_FILTER" if the pojo doesn't have @JsonFilter annotation.
String jsonPerson = mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(jai).writer(filters).writeValueAsString(new Person());
String jsonUser = mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(jai).writer(filters).writeValueAsString(new User());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The filter idea is a good one, however the filters will override the @JsonView's. So to fully implement this, I'll need to drop all the Views and implement the View-like behavior in a JsonFilter. This isn't ideal as it introduce a bunch of new code separate from the POJOs.